# Java Game Development- Sprites colliding?

Tags: java, sprite, collision

This is my first question so excuse me if I break any rules or something.

I have been developing a Mario game and I am working on drawing sprites. I am trying to nail collision detection. With research, i learned that you could use the Rectangle class to do this so...

```
 public void checkCollisions() {
    Rectangle mr = mario.getBounds();
    Rectangle gr = goomba.getBounds();
    if(mr.intersects(gr)) {
        System.out.println("Collision detected");
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    updateMario();
    checkCollisions();
    repaint();
}
```

However this spams the collision method even when mario is half a screen away from the other sprite!

So the overall question is, how do i get the system not to spam the message when the sprites are away from each other?

Classes:
http://pastebin.com/PHWTzSvQ

I used the Zetcode game resource by the way.

Comment: What is your question? Also, don't post code in other links. If it's relevant to your question, post it in the question.

Comment: my question is how to get the system not to spam the collision method when the sprites are far away from each other as it's not supposed to.

Comment: Well, you kind of can't, each cycle, you need to be checking what your character "might" be colliding with

Comment: This is usually called scene management. You might divide your world into a cube which you slice into smaller parts and do the same thing recursively and assign the objects to each leaf-cube the object is located in (bsp-trees, quad-tree, octtree, ...) You then have to check only surrounding cubes if they contain objects. Although SO is not the platform for recommendations, I think David Brackeens [Developing Games in Java](http://www.brackeen.com/javagamebook/) is probably one of the best resources literature-wise for Java and Game Development out there.

Comment: As you implement a 2D game, a cube might not be the best thing - as you hardly deal with z coordinates. Therefore think of a small 2D paper you put onto your world which you then divide into smaller rectangles. Though, this is only one possible solution - there are a couple of different techniques. Try to read some of them and use what fits your approach best.

Comment: Ah yeah, i meant squares not cubes. Okay I'll look some more

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

Instead of the intersect method i used a method that turned the sprite location into a string:

```
public String getLocationAsString() {
    return x+" "+y;
}
```

And then i used this

```
 public void checkCollisions() {
    if(mario.getLocationAsString().equalsIgnoreCase(goomba.getLocationAsString())) {
        System.out.println("Collision");
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help! (Also yay for first question)